# loop with while without to print all iterations

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, each

How can I do a loop using `while` to calculate the sum `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 300`, and to print the results every 20 iterations only.

I tryied to build the command below, but it is not working:

```
soma_300=0
i=0
while(i< 300){
  if (i/20 == integer) {
    print(i)
  }
  i=i+1

  soma_300=soma_300+i
}
soma_300
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry! I'm using R. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can try to use another counter like this

```
soma_300=0
i=0
c=0
while(i< 300) {
  i=i+1
  soma_300=soma_300 + i
  c=c+1
  if (c == 20) {
    print(i)
    c = 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the rest of the division of `i` by `20`is `0`. To do that, you want to use `%%`.

```
soma_300=0
i=0

while(i < 300){
  if (i %% 20 == 0) {
    print(i)
  }
  i=i+1

  soma_300=soma_300+i
}
[1] 0
[1] 20
[1] 40
[1] 60
[1] 80
[1] 100
[1] 120
[1] 140
[1] 160
[1] 180
[1] 200
[1] 220
[1] 240
[1] 260
[1] 280
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with R, but you might try with the modulus operator `%%`.
This seems to work:

```
sum = 0
i = 0

while(i < 300) {
  if (i %% 20 == 0) {
    print(i)
  }
  i = i + 1

  sum = sum + i
}
sum
```